# Only log specific Doctrine entity actions / events / updates

Tags: logging, symfony, doctrine, entity

My current Symfony/Doctrine application consists of 10-15 entities, ofcourse with relations between them. An important feature that I need to implement is the logging of specific actions. It are not the SQL-entries I want to store.

To make this more clear: Assume I have an author and a book (with a 1..n relation). Besides writing books, authors also can review books and the current working reviewer can change.

I need to create a new log entry of the date, time, book, author, every time a new reviewer is accepting or declining to review the book. Those entiries need to be stored in the database.

Ofcourse I've started with searching, for now [Doctrine LifeCyle events](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/events.html) is a step in the right way. My question is or it is the right solution. Is there a better / faster way to solve my usecase?

Answer (score 1):

Making a custom doctrine event subscriber is quite strait-forward using symfony2,

but if you want a preexisting solution, I can link yout to https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors#loggable

I can help you using it if needed.

Comment: Sounds good, but what makes this Bundle a better solution than the regular Doctrine lifecycles?

Comment: It uses Doctrine subscribers internally. It juste eases registration of specified entities logging.

Comment: Side question: but what's the benefit of the KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors over the Gedmo/DoctrineExtensions? (Geocodable being an obvious exception due to it being a "new" behaviour/extension)